# How to run Console and Form at the same time

Tags: java, console

I want to write to console and draw on a form, I tried to use

```
  Console cnsl = null;
      PrintWriter out = null;
       // creates a console object
         cnsl = System.console();

         // if console is not null
         if (cnsl != null) {

            // creates new print writer
            out = cnsl.writer();

            // prints
            out.println("Here is The Optimus Prime!!");
         }
```

but it didn't open a console window, it opened the form window only !

Comment: Short answer, don't.  Either make a GUI or make it texted based, not both.

Comment: I have to make it this way, but why you are saying that?

Comment: You're crossing metaphors.  A GUI should allow the user to interact with from it's own context, not from the console, this is not how GUIs work.  A GUI is event driven where is a console is procedurally/linearly driven. The question is, why do you need to use both this way?

Comment: Because you either are in console or in windowed ui mode. But you can try to emulate a console inside a windowed ui.

Comment: How do you run your app?